# Attach the mail sent by workflow

Tags: workflow, attachment

actually in our org we send emails using workflows. The business required to attach the sent mail to the related record. There is anyway to do this?

Comment: You're saying it's not good enough to also log a task from the same workflow rule, that it must be the sent email?

Comment: Yes, you are right, the requirement is to attach the sent email, and not just to have a task that notify that the mail was sent. Do you know a available solution? thnks

Answer (score 1):

Emails sent from workflows are not automatically logged as tasks but you can add a task as one of the workflow actions to represent the email that was sent. However, this might not not be a practical solution if you have a lot of workflows sending emails in multiple objects.

Comment: Thnks @PepeFloyd for your feedback, but the requirement is to attach exactely the sent mail.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways to accomplish what you're attempting to do is with an apex Email Service and email compliance. Salesforce allows you to automatically BCC all emails to a compliance address.

You could make this compliance address an email service, associated with an apex class to do the parsing and attach the email to the corresponding record.